# Simple Scheduler using quartz getting Error in java

Tags: java, exception, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am trying to make Scheduler using Quartz. I have tried this example

```
 JobDetail detail = new JobDetail();
 detail.setName("dummyJobName");
 detail.setJobClass(HelloWorld.class);
 System.out.println("Scheduler First Example");
 SimpleTrigger simpleTrigger = new SimpleTrigger();
 simpleTrigger.setName("dummyTriggerName");
 simpleTrigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
 simpleTrigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
 simpleTrigger.setRepeatInterval(10000);
 Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
 scheduler.scheduleJob(detail, simpleTrigger);
 scheduler.start();
```

but using this i am getting error like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.quartz.SchedulerException: 
                                           Job's group cannot be null
```

please can anybody Help me with this.?

Comment: I believe Exception's message is very informative in this case :-)

Comment: @NikolayLagutko can u Elaborate it plz?

Comment: every job is identified by a individual name and group name to which is belongs to. You have used detail.setName(). There must be another function called detail.setGroupName() or something similar

Comment: yes Right i already Solved it. now :)

Comment: I did. :) and ya i solved it before that but your ans is right so accepted. .:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every job is identified by a individual name and group name to which is belongs to. You have used 'detail.setName()' 
There must be another function called 
detail.setGroupName() or something similar –